# Android Emulator - Cannot take screenshot

Tags: android

I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0.
If an emulator, ran by Android AVD in Android Studio, is using host GPU - the emulator is running smoothly, but I cannot take a screenshot, because when I click here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/taoed.png]

The following message doesn't close unless I click "Cancel":
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O99yM.png]

**Also**, if I open Android Device Monitor and click here:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W72bZ.png]

The following window pops up:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqtfL.png]

However, if I **don't** use host GPU, the emulator screen stays black, even if I check "Store a snapshot for faster startup".

## UPDATE

**JonasCz**, those screenshot explain everything:
If I **uncheck** "Use host GPU", the screen is black:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXTHy.png]

If I **check** "Use host GPU", the emulator is running *but* I'm unable to take screenshots (doesn't matter if I try to take via "Android Device Monitor" or via "Android DDMS"): 
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVnhz.jpg]

Comment: Why not take a screen-shot of your entire desktop ('Print Screen' key), and if you only want a screen-shot of the emulator screen, you can crop it.

Comment: Seems to be a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60359)

Comment: @JonasCz, I need the screenshot for Google Play.

Comment: Why not take screen-shot of your entire desktop, crop, and use for Google play ?

Comment: Because it depends on my screen resolution, which is not high enough. I need to take screenshot straight from the device, because I will get the screenshot in full resolution.

Comment: What OS are you using on your development machine? There is a known issue with Linux where Host GPU mode on prevents screenshots from working.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 Pro Tech Preview.

Comment: You could take the screenshot on a real device, maybe ?

Comment: @JonasCz, I need to take a screenshot from an Android TV. If I had this, I wouldn't need to use an emulator.

Comment: Can you try to turn _off_  'Use host GPU' , and then take the screenshot ? Might work even though the screen is black. You could also try on a different computer.

Comment: @JonasCz, I updated the main post. Please take a look.

Comment: What happens when you try to take screenshot at the black screen ?

Comment: @JonasCz The output is as the output if the emulator does work - "Screen not available".